# How can I access the container in a before kernel listener in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, service, kernel, listener, before-filter

I try to implement a before kernel listener ([see reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)) where I simply set some parameter values (that I have to fetch dynamically and cannot statically declare in my `parameters.yml` file).

This is my listener class:

```
class AcmeListener
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getController()->getContainer()->setParameter('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

And in my `config.yml`:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.acme_listener:
        class: Acme\AcmeBundle\EventListener\AcmeListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

But I get a

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getContainer() on a non-object

How can I access the container, if not via `getContainer()` from the `$event->getController()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the container as an argument into your service definition.

```
services:
    kernel.listener.acme_listener:
        class: Acme\AcmeBundle\EventListener\AcmeListener
        arguments:
            - @service_container
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Then add a constructor to your AcmeListener class so you can access it.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class AcmeListener
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Container $container
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
            $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
            $this->container->...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I get a `LogicException: Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.`

Comment: Do I have to switch to the `onKernelRequest` instead of `onKernelController`?

Comment: Possibly. Looking back at the time I did this I used onKernelRequest. Does that still suit your needs?

Comment: I see your issue now. The docs offer some info on this:
"You can only set a parameter before the container is compiled. To learn more about compiling the container see Compiling the Container."
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Comment: You should accept @Mark's answer as it shows how to access the container.  Though personally I would have implemented the ContainerAware interface instead of injecting the container into the constructor.  But his solution works.  Updating a frozen parameter bag is another question completely and is basically not possible.  You need to do this sort of thing using semantic configuration.

Comment: @Cerad yeah you're right. The answer explains how to access the container so I accept it. Thanks to you - Mark - for your help :-) I'll pose another question concerning the FrozenParameter issue.

Comment: By the way: using `onKernelRequest` still invokes the same error.